# c# write listbox contents into a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, text-files, streamwriter

I want to print contents from the list box to a text file but it seems not working. SortedFlats text file shows nothing.

```
protected void printImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter flatStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") + "SortedFlats.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < flatListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        flatStreamWriter.WriteLine(flatListBox.Items[i].ToString());
    }
    flatStreamWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: `Server.MapPath` ? Winforms?

Comment: sorry it's not winforms. it's web application.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely you need to issue a `Flush`.

But, how about something a bit more resource friendly:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < flatListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(flatListBox.Items[i].ToString());
}
File.WriteAllText("SortedFlats.txt"), sb.ToString());
```

By using `File.WriteAllText` you're not having to manage the unmanaged resources on your own. Which you're doing wrong right now anyway because it's not wrapped in a `using`.

Finally, don't use `Server.MapPath` in a winforms application. That is for mapping a virtual web path to a real physical path.